# Compile issues with Zurb Foundation in mimosa

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass, durandal-2.0, mimosa

I am trying to use Zurb-Foundation CSS framework in my Durandal JS project which uses Mimosa/sass/compass to compile sass files.

With a semantic approach, I am wanting to use the Foundations sass files and use foundations mixins/classes directly in my sass files.

However, no matter what approach I use to pull in the foundation project files into my project (whether using mimosa or manually), I can't get passed the compile errors I receive. Mainly the

```
undefined variable: $include-html-classes
```

for each sass file that uses it.

The variable is a defined variable in the _variables.scss file which is included in the foundation.scss file.  This error is included for every partial that uses it.  But I can't see why this is the since the _variables.scss is hosted in the foundation.scss file.

**note** I have attempted to include the variables partial directly.

For those answers related to using compass - according to the mimosa documentation, by default it uses Compass for sass compiling unless explicitly defining a node compiler.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable partial the first file that is being included in your foundation.scss ?

`@import "foundation/variables";`

Are your _variables.scss un-commented? 
They come commented by default.

If you don't include _variables.scss or they are all commented out, then 
is your `_global.scss` being included? As the first import?

If both fail, try adding the below to your foundation.scss and let me know if this works

`$include-html-classes: true !default;`